# Mysql Joining two tables and avoid duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this following table

**table1**

```
id    name  
1    joseph
2    john
3    george
4    lisa
5    michelle
```

**table2**

```
id    city
1    New York
2    Los Angeles
3    Chicago
```

I need to get all data in table1 and assign a random city from table2

here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN (Select * From `table2` Order by Rand()) as temp
ON 1 = 1
```

the problem is that the output looks like this

```
joseph    New York 
joseph    Chicago
joseph    Los Angeles
john      New York 
john      Chicago
john      Los Angeles
george    New York 
george    Chicago
george    Los Angeles
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a sub-query in the select:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  (SELECT city FROM `table2` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) random_city
FROM `table1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LIMIT` when querying the city table

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN (Select * From `table2` Order by Rand() LIMIT 1) as temp
ON 1 = 1
```